# Best practices for overall rating calculation

Tags: algorithm, rating

I have LAMP-based business application. SugarCRM to be more precise. There are 120+ active users at the moment. Every day each user generates some records that are used in complex calculation to get so called “individual rating”.

It takes for about 6 seconds to calculate one “individual rating” value. And there was not a big problem before: each user hits the link provided to start “individual rating” calculations, waits for 6-7 seconds, and get the value displayed.

But now I need to implement “overall rating” calculation. That means that additionally to “individual rating” I have to calculate and display to the user:

- minimum individual rating among ALL the users of the application
- maximum individual rating among ALL the users of the application
- current user position in the range of all individual ratings.

Say, current user has individual rating equal to 220 points, minimum value of rating is 80, maximum is 235 and he is on 23rd position among all the users.

What are (imho) the main problems to be solved?

1. If one calculation lasts for 6 seconds, that overall calculations will take more than 10 minutes. I think it’s no good to make the application almost unaccessible for this period. And what if the quantity of users will rise in the nearest future 2-3 times?
2. Those calculations could be done as nightly job but all the users are in different timezones. In Russia difference between extreme timezones is 9 hours. So people in west part of Russia are still working in “today”. While people in eastern part is waking up to work in “tomorrow”. So what is the best time for nightly job in this case?

Are there any best practices|approaches|algorithms to build such rating system?

Comment: I guess the main problem is: Why should it take 6-7 seconds to calculate one rating?

Comment: This is mostly the time of executing SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Given only the information provided, the only options I see:

1. The obvious one - reduce the time taken for a rating calculation (6 seconds to calculate 1 user's rating seems like a lot)
2. If possible, have intermediate values which you only recalculate some of, as required (for example, have 10 values that make up the rating, all based on different data, when some of the data changes, flag the appropriate values for recalcuation). Either do this recalculation:

   - During your daily recalculation or
   - When the update happens
3. Partial batch calculation - only recalculate x of the users' ratings at chosen intervals (where x is some chosen value) - has the disadvantage that, at all times, some of the ratings can be out of date
4. Calculate if not busy - either continuously recalculate ratings or only do so at a chosen interval, but instead of locking the system, have it run as a background process, only doing work if the system is idle

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry, didn't manage with "long" comment posting; so decided to post as answer)

@Dukeling

SQL query that takes almost all the time for calculation mentioned above is just a replication of business logic that should be executed in PHP code. The logic was moved into SQL with the hope to reduce calculation time. OK, I’ll try both to optimize SQL query and play with executing logic in PHP code.

Suppose after that optimized application calculates individual rating for just 1 second. Great! But even in this case the first user logged into system should awaits for 120 seconds (120+ users  * 1 sec = 120 sec) to calculate overall rating and gets its position in it.

I’m thinking of implementing the following approach:

1. Let’s have 2 “overall ratings” – “today” and “yesterday”.
2. For displaying purposes we’ll use “yesterday” overall rating represented as huge already sorted PHP array.
3. When user hits calculation link he started “today” calculation but application displays him “yesterday” value. Thus we have quickly accessible “yesterday” rating and each user randomly launches rating calculation that will be displayed for them tomorrow.
4. User list are partitioned by timezones. Each hour a cron job started to check if there’re any users in selected timezone that don’t have “today” individual rating calculated (e.g. user didn’t log into application). If so, application starts calculation of individual rating and puts its value in “today” (still invisible) ovarall rating array. Thus we have a cron job that runs nightly for each timezone-specific user group and fills the probable gaps in case users didn’t log into system.
5. After all users in all timezones had been worked out, application

   1. sorts “today” array,
   2. drops “yesterday” one,
   3. rename “today” in “yesterday” and
   4. initialize new “today”.

What do you think of it? Is it reasonable enough or not?